# How can 1000 divided into 5 give 250?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

A small discussion in the middle of [Who Mourns for Morn?](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Who_Mourns_for_Morn%3F_(episode)) episode [includes](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/536.htm) following:

> QUARK: We could split the latinum **five ways**. That's what you would've gotten if Morn was still alive.
>
> LARELL: That's true.
>
> QUARK: Think of me as Morn. I can't believe I just said that.
>
> NAHSK: This isn't fair. We stole it. He had nothing to do with it.
>
> QUARK: Maybe not, but the bottom line is you need me.
>
> HAIN: A **thousand bricks of latinum** split **five ways**. What do you think?
>
> KRIT: It's still a lot of latinum.
>
> NAHSK: That's **two hundred and fifty bricks** each.

(emphasis mine)

Is there a small nuance behind (Nahsk meaning that Quark is not going to get his part after all) or did the script writer make a simple mathematical mistake, not knowing that 1000 / 5 = 200, no 250?

Comment: Maybe that was a traditional Ferengi trick? Nahsk "accidentally" miscalculating in his favor hoping the others would not correct him until they paid him out and realized he got away with too much?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I'd have accepted an answer with a memory alpha quote over an answer that had a quote directly from the screenplay.

Comment: Having never watched the show, my "outsider" mindset would lead me to believe this is a foreshadowing riddle. If there is an "unforeseen" tragedy for one of the 5 people then 250 bricks per person sounds plausible. Yes, I do see the accepted answer but just thought I would share my 2/50th of a dollar :-)

Comment: I vote to migrate this to Puzzling.SE, remove the background info and watch them struggle.

Comment: @user1717828 Cruelty, is your name, huh? :>

Comment: You can also take it as a menacing thing to say that everyone thinks they're in on, but one really isn't and they're going to get killed or whatever. That's how the Ferengi work...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is deliberate mistake on the part of the writers to flesh out the character of Nahsk.

Later on the writers use the fact that Nahsk is slow to make an argument happen between Nahsk and his brother.

Quote from Memory Alpha:

> Krit says Hain is outgunned, as his brother may be "slow," but he'll get Hain in the end.

This leads to the breakdown and the fight between the four people trying to get the Latinum.

Comment: A Ferengi bad at calculating profit is somewhat unrealistic, though...

Comment: NAHSK is not a ferengi however http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Nahsk He is of unknown race

Comment: Having taught people who are also not very good with math, I think this script is fairly unrealistic. People who aren't good with math invariably know it and keep their mouths shut when math is involved so they don't reveal their weakness.

Comment: @benhocking - His weakness seems to be that he doesn't know that he's thick

Comment: @BenHocking: This is an extremely common trope on television.

Comment: @BenHocking I know people who are bad at mental arithmetic who don't hesitate to blurt out wrong answers.  They're not necessarily bad at math (they can do algebra and calculus on paper), so they don't keep their mouths shut when math is involved.

Comment: @BenHocking I'm not sure about math itself, but aside of it, I know a really lot of people, who doesn't know anything about given subject and yet, not only keep their mouths shut when this topic is involved, but they're trying to pose as ultimate source of knowledge on that, in addition.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - Dumb people saying dumb things isn't just a trope on telly, it's also pretty common in real life.

Answer (score 76):

Nahsk isn't the brightest star in the sky. The [original screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/536.txt) describes him thusly

> Nahsk is the "muscle" of this duo, and **a bit slower than his brother.**

and offers the following stage direction when he makes his error

> **HAIN:** *A thousand bricks, split five ways... what do you think?*
>
> **KRIT:** *It's still a lot of latinum.*
>
> **NAHSK:** (nods) *Two hundred and fifty bricks each.*
>
> **They all look at Nahsk, decide not to bother correcting him --**

Comment: Doesn't get much more authoritative than that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Much more authoritative than... what? 10 up votes on your comment, which I don't get at all (maybe lack of coffee?).

Comment: @trejder: Than a direct quote from the screenplay.

Comment: @trejder - The other answer is quoting from memory-alpha, a fan-written wiki site. Their answer isn't *wrong*, just based on a lower level source

Comment: Got that. Thanks both of you.

Comment: @trejder:   So why don't you correct which answer is accepted?!

Comment: @ThePopMachine Well... (a) because I agree with _Lightness Races in Orbit_ and I don't find this answer that much better, (b) because I don't like to be pushed into selecting any answer by any means, (c) because JamesD's answer was first, (d) because Valorum has a gigantic rep and won't notice that +25, (e) because... name any other argument.

Comment: @trejder - I think you may have misunderstood Lightness Races in Orbit's comment. He's saying that answers don't get much more authoritative ***than this one*** since it directly references the show's screenplay.

Comment: @trejder:   I sympathize with your reasons, but this answer really is superior and more highly upvoted for good reason.   You shouldn't avoid selecting the best answer for petty reasons.